# Fulton & Harris Proof Clarification for Lemma D.6

Tags: proof-explanation, lie-algebras, nilpotence, semisimple-lie-algebras

Lemma D.6 of Fulton & Harris claims

> If $H$ is regular, then $\mathfrak g_0(H)$ is abelian,

where $\mathfrak g$ is a complex Lie algebra, $\mathfrak g_0(H)=\ker\operatorname{ad}(H)^m$ for large $m$, and "regular" has been temporarily defined to mean $\dim\mathfrak g_0(H)\leqslant\dim\mathfrak g_0(X)$ for all $X \in \mathfrak g$. Though it is a bit unclear what is being assumed, it seems that $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple (this fact is used explicitly in the proof), while $H\in\mathfrak g$ can be arbitrary (i.e., $H$ is not necessarily semisimple/diagonalizable).

The first two paragraphs show that the Killing form $B$, when restricted to $\mathfrak g_0(H)$, is nondegenerate. I understand this part. The third paragraph is as follows.

> Consider the Jordan decomposition $X = X_s + X_n$ of an element $X\in\mathfrak g_0(H)$. Since $\operatorname{ad}(X_n)=\operatorname{ad}(X)_n$ is nilpotent, $X_n$ belongs to $\mathfrak g_0(H)$, so $X_s = X - X_n$ does also. Then $\operatorname{ad}(X_s) = \operatorname{ad}(X)_s$ is nilpotent and semisimple on $\mathfrak g_0(H)$, so it vanishes there.

I don't understand the implications

1. ad$(X_n)$ is nilpotent $\implies X_n\in\mathfrak g_0(H)$
2. $X_s\in\mathfrak g_0(H)\implies X_s$ is nilpotent.

If this follows immediately from the definitions, or from the surrounding propositions in the chapter, I cannot see it. Please help clarify these claims.

Comment: I don't know if this is what they are using but note that $\mathrm{ad}(X_s),\mathrm{ad}(X_n)$ are polynomials in $\mathrm{ad}(X)$ without constant term so they commute with $H$ if $X$ does. Source for this statement can be found in the Jordan decomposition section in Humphreys (but may also be in Fulton and Harris somewhere). This answers the first part at least.